# WebSphere with Oracle database

Tags: oracle, websphere-7

I was trying to configure the WebSphere Application Server with Oracle database.While following the documentation, it compelled me to create J2C authentication aliases.

When checked we have two options are there to create this:

1. Resources -> JDBC -> Data sources -> Related Items -> JAAS - J2C authentication data
2. Security > Global Security ->Java Authentication and Authorization Service > J2C authentication data

My question is: are both the above same?

I have configured using the second option. And completed the configuration. Tested the datasource connections.

How can I check whether the configuration process is correct or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , both paths go to the same J2C authentication data page. The first path from the data source is a short-cut to alleviate having to go thru the Security path. If the test connection was successful, that will confirm the provider and data source were configured correctly.
VS, opinions are my own and not those of my employer